# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' ORDER BY 'ID'' at line 1

Tags: mysql

I have this line,

```
$query = "SELECT Food, Calories Title FROM 'users' ORDER BY 'ID'";
```

I'm so worried about my syntax, when I run it it gives me an error as,

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''users' ORDER BY 'ID'' at line 1

Comment: single quote is used to delimit string values, not table and field names.

Comment: Bro now it is as error, 
No database selected @Uueerdo

Comment: A decent book or tutorial would probably be more useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've represented the line exactly as written, but your code lacks a comma after the word 'calories', as in 
"SELECT Food, Calories, Title FROM 'users' ORDER BY 'ID'"

Comment: And technically that is allowed, which is why I hate that `As` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Select Food, Calories, Title 
FROM users 
ORDER BY ID

Answer (score -1):

$query = "SELECT `Food`, `Calories Title` FROM `users` ORDER BY `ID`";

Comment: use (``) this qoutes for food,Calories Title,users and ID